# A problem with a table im my beamer documentclass

Tags: tables, beamer

Can the table in the screenshot below be shifted a little to the left ?
 [image]

Here is my code concerning the slide containing this table

```
\begin{frame}
%\begin{table}[ht]
%\caption{}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}    \hline
                Algebras                                    &{\sf At-can.}&{\sf At. gen}& {\sf El. gen}.                        & {\sf Can.}  & {\sf Str} is el. &{\sf CR} is el.& $\sf VT$\\


                                                           \hline
                                                                      ${\sf RCA}_n$, $\sf RRA$ &no&yes&yes&yes&no&no&no\\

                                                           \hline
                                                                      $\bold S{\sf Nr}_n\CA_{n+1}$   &yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&?& ?\\

                                                           \hline
                                                                      $\bold S\Ra\CA_3, \bold S\Ra\CA_4$  &yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&yes& yes\\



                                                           \hline
                                                                      $\bold S{\sf Nr}_n\CA_{n+2}$ &?&yes&yes&yes&?&?&?\\


                                                           \hline
                                                                      $\bold S\Ra\CA_5$ &?&yes&yes&yes&?&yes&yes\\

                                                           \hline
                                                                      $\bold S{\sf Nr}_n\CA_{n+k}$, $\bold S\Ra\CA_m$  &no&yes&yes&yes&?&no&no\\


                                                                       %\hline
                                                                      %$\bold S{\sf Nr}_n{\sf D}_{n+k}$  &no&no&yes&?\\



                                                                       \hline
                                                                      ${\sf D}_n, {\sf G}_n$  &yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&yes\\








                                                                      \hline

  \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}
```

As mentioned in the title, I use beamer documentclass.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `\hspace*{-1cm}\begin{tabular}...` ?

Comment: The last column does not appear in my slide. It it possible to decrease the width of each column a little? I think this will solve the problem. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Yes I do @Mico .

Comment: And how are `\CA` and `\Ra` defined?

Comment: It works. This is not the problem I inquire about

Comment: put `\small` before the table? really you have been on the site long enough to know that you should provide a proper example that allows answers to be tested.

Comment: But the table still with the same size after adding such a command @DavidCarlisle

Comment: make a proper example then answers can be tested! (but `\small` needs to be inside the table before tabular, not before `\begin{table}`)

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Reduce the value of `\tabcolsep`, the parameter that governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace, and switch the relative font size to `\small`.
- Get rid of all vertical rules and most horizontal rules. Use the macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline`.
- Increase the value of `\arraystretch` to create a more "open" look.
- Don't use the Plain-TeX command `\sf`. Instead, use either `\textsf` or `\mathsf`, as appropriate.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\CA{CA} %??
\newcommand\Ra{Ra} %??
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.75pt} % default is 6pt
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{7}{c}@{}}    
\toprule
Algebras  &At-can.& At.\ gen & El.\ gen. & Can. & Str is el. & CR is el. & $\mathsf{VT}$\\
\midrule
$\mathsf{RCA}_n$, $\mathsf{RRA}$          &no&yes&yes&yes&no&no&no\\
$\mathbf{S}\mathsf{Nr}_n\CA_{n+1}$        &yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&?& ?\\    
$\mathbf{S}\Ra\CA_3, \mathbf{S}\Ra\CA_4$  &yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&yes& yes\\    
$\mathbf{S}\mathsf{Nr}_n\CA_{n+2}$        &?&yes&yes&yes&?&?&?\\    
$\mathbf{S}\Ra\CA_5$                      &?&yes&yes&yes&?&yes&yes\\    
$\mathbf{S}\mathsf{Nr}_n\CA_{n+k}$, $\mathbf{S}\Ra\CA_m$  &no&yes&yes&yes&?&no&no\\
%$\mathbf{S}\mathsf{Nr}_n\mathsf{D}_{n+k}$  &no&no&yes&?\\
$\mathsf{D}_n, \mathsf{G}_n$              &yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&yes\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If the intercolumn whitespace in the preceding solution isn't quite wide enough for your taste, you'll need to reduce the font size a bit more, viz., go from `\small` to `\footnotesize`. Then, use a `\tabular*` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, and let LaTeX figure out the optimal (i.e., maximally permissible) amount of intercolumn whitespace.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\CA{\mathsf{CA}} %?
\newcommand\Ra{\mathsf{Ra}} %?
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out optimal amount of whitespace
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{c}}    
\toprule
Algebras  &At-can.& At.\ gen & El.\ gen. & Can. & Str is el. & CR is el. & $\mathsf{VT}$\\
\midrule
$\mathsf{RCA}_n$, $\mathsf{RRA}$          &no&yes&yes&yes&no&no&no\\
$\mathbf{S}\mathsf{Nr}_n\CA_{n+1}$        &yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&?& ?\\
$\mathbf{S}\Ra\CA_3$, $\mathbf{S}\Ra\CA_4$&yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&yes& yes\\
$\mathbf{S}\mathsf{Nr}_n\CA_{n+2}$        &?&yes&yes&yes&?&?&?\\
$\mathbf{S}\Ra\CA_5$                      &?&yes&yes&yes&?&yes&yes\\
$\mathbf{S}\mathsf{Nr}_n\CA_{n+k}$, $\mathbf{S}\Ra\CA_m$ &no&yes&yes&yes&?&no&no\\
%$\mathbf{S}\mathsf{Nr}_n\mathsf{D}_{n+k}$ &no&no&yes&?\\
$\mathsf{D}_n$, $\mathsf{G}_n$            &yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&yes&yes\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very good. I need something more. How can I put a separation between each column, as done in my example? .

Comment: @HusseinEid - The table doesn't need the vertical bars -- unless you're fond of the "prison cell window" look...

Comment: @HusseinEid - I've provided a second solution, which uses `\footnotesize` instead of `\small` as the (relative) font size. That way, it's possible to increase the amount of intercolumn whitespace a bit. (I still wouldn't use vertical bars, though...)